# Query pardot with a list of Prospect Ids

Tags: apex, pardot

I have a list of prospect Ids that I need to query pardot about.

I could only find a way to query a range of prospect ids using id_greater_than and id_less_than, so if I'll sort my list of prospects it will be possible to use the first and last prospect Ids, but then I'll get unwanted records in the results.

Any idea of another way to query pardot with a list of prospect Ids? I'm using apex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to **query** with a list of IDs.

You can either try to work around it playing with the query id greater / less than parameters, or you can just do READ operations for each prospect.

Use the Query if you have large contiguous blocks of Prospect IDs, otherwise READ will be better performant (especially if you use output=simple).

Down side to the READ operation is that you can't specify which fields you want to get.

Comment: Thanks, @adam!
Read was faster indeed. But, it cant be done for a bulk of prospects, am I right?

Comment: Correct. 1 at a time